# Java http request for django rest framework service throws http 406 exception

Tags: java, django, http, django-rest-framework

I hava a django rest framework web service that works fine with httpie and firefox: when I request with httpie I have a json formatted answer and when I request with firefox an html formatted one (httpie is a http client).
Now I'm building java API to communicate with services. I'm using URL class to perform requests. 
I can receive html-formatted answers from the server if I don't override the content-type property. So I looked how httpie overrides this property and did the same:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*\\*");
```

Now the communication end with Http 406 error, which means that client can't accept the answer.

If I use only the content-type property I have no error but still the html-formatted answer

Does anyone know how to solve it?

EDIT (adding requests' header):

httpie:
    GET /match/39.3280114/16.241917599999965/0/5/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
    Connection: keep-alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept: */*
    User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.3

java-API
    GET /match/39.3280114/16.241917599999965/0/5/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept: **
    User-Agent: Java-API

Solved: I was using the wrong slash for Accept property

Comment: Can you show the full headers of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Accept` header is malformed. It should be:

```
Accept: */*
```

See [RFC 7231 § 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2).

However, `*/*` means “any media type.” If you actually want a specific media type (JSON), you should request it:

```
Accept: application/json
```